# Amazon SNS - aws-sdk-php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

```php
     $accessKey = 'XZA...';
     $accessSecret = 'YKW...';
     $credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials($accessKey, $accessSecret);

     $sharedConfig = [
        'region'  => 'us-east-1',          
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => $credentials
    ];

     $sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);
     $sns = new SnsClient($sharedConfig);

     $payload = [
        'PhoneNumber' => '+999999999',   // E.164 format
        'Message' => md5(time()),
        'MessageAttributes' => [
          'DefaultSenderID' => ['DataType'=>'String','StringValue'=>'MyBrandName'],
          'DefaultSMSType' => ['DataType'=>'String','StringValue'=>'Transactional']
        ]
    ];

    try {
        $data = $sns->publish( $payload );
        $MessageId = $data->get('MessageId');
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {   }
```

I'm using the AWS SDK for PHP - Version 3. 
The code above works well when i'm sending a single SMS message except the attribute **DefaultSenderID** wich is not working when i send a SMS to a mobile device.

Amazon documentation says that **DefaultSenderID** – A string, such as your business brand, that is displayed as the sender on the receiving device. Support for sender IDs varies by country. The sender ID can be 1 - 11 alphanumeric characters, and it must contain at least one letter.

Anyone has experienced this problem using the Amazon SNS?

Comment: Can you add your full php file, Is there any other functions / methods in the script or does the script currently require any of the aws sdk files? It will help if the full php file can be added, Otherwise if the is resolved can you please let others know it has been resolved and how you resolved the issue.

Comment: The only thing is missing in the code above is the require_once 'autoload..php'. The full script is the code above. And the issue remains...

Answer (score 1):

For anybody still struggling with this.

If you look at the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_sdk), you will find that you need to add the key *AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID* to the payload's *MessageAttributes*.

The following should work:

```
$payload = [
    'PhoneNumber' => '+999999999', // E.164 format
    'Message' => md5(time()),
    'MessageAttributes' => [
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'YourSenderID',
        ]
    ]
];

try {
    $data = $sns->publish($payload);
    $MessageId = $data->get('MessageId');
} catch (Exception $e) { }
```

Comment: They are talking about that in the docs in a VERY cryptic way here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_sdk

Comment: Also, if you're doing this with node.js... you can add the attribute to your parameter list like this.
         var params = {
        Message: req.body.msg, /* required */
        PhoneNumber: req.body.phoneNum, /* required */
        DefaultSenderID: 'OurCompany' /* 1-11 alphanumeric */
        };
 Look under parameters: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sns-examples-sending-sms.html